# Reference function's scope while inside another function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass a function into another function, but use the scope of the second function inside the first. I have a javascript background, so I'm used to doing things like:

```
function write(str, path) {
    // do stuff
}

function doThis(fn) {
    fn()
}

function doThisString(str, path) {
    doThis(function() {
      write(str, path)
    });
}
```

How can i do this in python?

Comment: Where in your snippet comes `doThis` into play? If you are referring to closures, python has those.

Comment: Sorry, see the edited code

Comment: I want to avoid nested function definitions. They look ugly and tend to become unmanageable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python equivalent would be.

```
def write (mystr, path): pass

def doThis (f): f ()

def doThisString (mystr, path):
    doThis (lambda: write (mystr, path) )
```

Or alternatively:

```
def doThisString (mystr, path):
    def function (): write (mystr, path)
    doThis (function)
```

Comment: `str` is a reserved keyword, you might change it to another one :)

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please explain what `lambda` does?

Comment: @dopatraman It is basically an anonymous function. That's all. Both snippets are (almost) equivalent.

Comment: @markcial You can use `str` if you want. You will just have hard time if you want to check the type after.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I've chosen to go with the 2nd technique. The thing is, the function I'm passing in is multi-line, so it ends up looking very ugly (up to 4 indents--Yuck). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Python supports closures. But except for the very limited (only a single expression) `lambda` form, functions must be defined in a separate statement before being used - they can't be created in an expression.

If you want to avoid nested function definitions for the sake of avoiding nesting, you can use `functools.partial`. Your specific example would be greatly simplified by it anyway:

```
from functools import partial

def doThisString(str, path):
    doThis(partial(write, str, path))
```

It doesn't always work out that well, so sometimes there are better alternatives.

Comment: Calling `lambda`s "very limited" is a bit unjust.

Comment: @Hyperboreus They *are* very limited, there's no wiggle room there. They can only contain a rather small subset of Python, and (as a consequence) can not express many computations -- unless you throw good style overboard (`d.__setitem__(key, value)` etc.).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: What part of restricted to *one* expression, no statements, makes `lambda`s *not* very limited?

Comment: @MartijnPieters This will make `lambda` limited in a context where you rely on assignments (the most missed statement inside lambdas). And it is true, that most python programs are such a context. However, if your program design is more of the functional persuasion than the imperative (with destructive assignment), then lambdas would be all you need (if only python supported TCO).

Comment: @MartijnPieters But I think this would now lead to a religious discussion and be unrelated to the question at hand.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: you may notice that I am not going to respond to all this. :-)

Comment: @Hyperboreus Ah, so you argue that the limitations of `lambda` don't always matter. I politely disagree about whether avoiding the things `lambda` prohibits is practical (pure FP in Python has far more problems than lack of TCO and `lambda`'s quirks), but in any case there *are* limitations. They may not always matter, but `lambda` is strictly less powerful/general than `def`.

Comment: @delnan Also a scanning electron microscope is strictly more powerful than my glasses. Although for every day use, I generally stick to my glasses without any limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it would look syntactically in python:

```
def write(text, path):
    // do stuff

def doThis(fn):
    fn()

def doThisString(text, path):
   doThis(lambda: write(text, path) )
```